# Why heroku saying couldn't find that app even when the build is successful?

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am trying to deploy my django app on heroku. I created an app, connected my app with github, selected automatic deploy and then manually deployed from my github master branch. The activity saying build successful and deployed. But whenever I'm trying to open the app it is raising an error. When I'm checking my logs it is saying **"Couldn't find that app"**

My build log:

```
-----> Python app detected
-----> Clearing cached dependencies
-----> Installing python-3.6.10
-----> Installing pip
-----> Installing SQLite3
Sqlite3 successfully installed.
-----> Installing requirements with pip
       Collecting django==3.0.4
         Downloading Django-3.0.4-py3-none-any.whl (7.5 MB)
       Collecting folium==0.10.1
         Downloading folium-0.10.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (91 kB)
       Collecting pandas==1.0.3
         Downloading pandas-1.0.3-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (10.0 MB)
       Collecting pytz
         Downloading pytz-2019.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (509 kB)
       Collecting asgiref~=3.2
         Downloading asgiref-3.2.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
       Collecting sqlparse>=0.2.2
         Downloading sqlparse-0.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (40 kB)
       Collecting branca>=0.3.0
         Downloading branca-0.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (25 kB)
       Collecting numpy
         Downloading numpy-1.18.2-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (20.2 MB)
       Collecting requests
         Downloading requests-2.23.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
       Collecting jinja2>=2.9
         Downloading Jinja2-2.11.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (125 kB)
       Collecting python-dateutil>=2.6.1
         Downloading python_dateutil-2.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (227 kB)
       Collecting six
         Downloading six-1.14.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
       Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17
         Downloading certifi-2020.4.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (157 kB)
       Collecting chardet<4,>=3.0.2
         Downloading chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
       Collecting urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1
         Downloading urllib3-1.25.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (125 kB)
       Collecting idna<3,>=2.5
         Downloading idna-2.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
       Collecting MarkupSafe>=0.23
         Downloading MarkupSafe-1.1.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (27 kB)
       Installing collected packages: pytz, asgiref, sqlparse, django, six, MarkupSafe, jinja2, branca, numpy, certifi, chardet, urllib3, idna, requests, folium, python-dateutil, pandas
       Successfully installed MarkupSafe-1.1.1 asgiref-3.2.7 branca-0.4.0 certifi-2020.4.5.1 chardet-3.0.4 django-3.0.4 folium-0.10.1 idna-2.9 jinja2-2.11.2 numpy-1.18.2 pandas-1.0.3 python-dateutil-2.8.1 pytz-2019.3 requests-2.23.0 six-1.14.0 sqlparse-0.3.1 urllib3-1.25.8
-----> $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/css/rtl.css'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/css/forms.css'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/css/widgets.css'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/css/autocomplete.css'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/css/fonts.css'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/css/responsive_rtl.css'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/css/dashboard.css'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/css/login.css'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/css/responsive.css'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/css/base.css'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/css/changelists.css'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/css/vendor/select2/LICENSE-SELECT2.md'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/css/vendor/select2/select2.css'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/css/vendor/select2/select2.min.css'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/fonts/Roboto-Bold-webfont.woff'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/fonts/LICENSE.txt'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/fonts/Roboto-Regular-webfont.woff'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/fonts/Roboto-Light-webfont.woff'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/fonts/README.txt'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/js/jquery.init.js'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/js/actions.min.js'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/js/SelectBox.js'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/js/actions.js'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/js/change_form.js'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/js/collapse.js'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/js/inlines.js'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/js/SelectFilter2.js'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/js/popup_response.js'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/bs.js'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/en.js'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/pt.js'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/fi.js'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/es.js'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/ka.js'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/ms.js'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/sl.js'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/nb.js'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/ca.js'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/zh-CN.js'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/bn.js'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/sr.js'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/he.js'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/hu.js'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/de.js'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/sq.js'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/ar.js'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/gl.js'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/az.js'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/vi.js'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/af.js'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/sv.js'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/hi.js'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/ro.js'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/zh-TW.js'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/pt-BR.js'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/sr-Cyrl.js'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/eu.js'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/lt.js'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/mk.js'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/sk.js'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/js/vendor/xregexp/xregexp.min.js'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/js/vendor/xregexp/LICENSE.txt'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/js/vendor/xregexp/xregexp.js'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/img/calendar-icons.svg'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/img/icon-addlink.svg'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/img/icon-unknown.svg'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/img/icon-clock.svg'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/img/tooltag-add.svg'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/img/LICENSE'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/img/icon-yes.svg'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/img/selector-icons.svg'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/img/icon-no.svg'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/img/inline-delete.svg'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/img/sorting-icons.svg'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/img/icon-alert.svg'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/img/icon-calendar.svg'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/img/icon-deletelink.svg'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/img/icon-unknown-alt.svg'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/img/search.svg'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/img/icon-changelink.svg'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/img/README.txt'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/img/gis/move_vertex_on.svg'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'admin/img/gis/move_vertex_off.svg'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       0 static files copied to '/tmp/build_83d39ccc7474e8d20461fa6a7c84bd8e/static', 131 unmodified.
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> (none)
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 86.8M
-----> Launching...
       Released v6
       https://coronainfobd.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

Upon opening the app it is throwing the following error:

```
Application error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command
heroku logs --tail
```

When I am running **"heroku logs -tail"** it is showing:

```
!    Couldn't find that app.
```

Answer (score 0):

on my terminal your app is showing me check if you miss spelled anything

```
$ heroku logs -a coronainfobd
 ▸    You do not have access to the app coronainfobd.
```